# React Native _statically_ required image stopped working without code change

Tags: ios, image, react-native

so I have this in my RN project:

```
<Image style={{padding: 0, height: 100, marginBottom: 40}} resizeMode='contain' source={require ('../assets/logo.png')} />
```

This exact code was working yesterday. Running again react-native run-ios without images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try giving width to Image. You may have changed flex/flexDirection styles of wrapping container of the Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```